# How can I make my server accept multiple clients in C? (TCP socket programming)

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

I am working on a TCP-IP chatroom and my server is only able to accept one client. This client is able to send messages and the server properly writes those back in the terminal it's running in.

The problem is that I would like to make my server accept multiple clients, but I don't know if that's possible without fork() or pthread.

My socket programming knowledge is very basic, this is a homework for me at university and I'm honestly stuck.

This is basically all I could achieve by watching tutorials and reading codes:

Client.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024                      
#define PORT_NO 2001                      
#define error(a,b) fprintf(stderr, a, b)  

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){ 

   int fd;                     
   int flags;                      
   struct sockaddr_in server;      
   struct sockaddr_in client;      
   int server_size;                
   int client_size;                
   int bytes;                      
   int rcvsize;                    
   int trnmsize;                   
   int err;                        
   char on;                        
   char buffer[BUFSIZE+1];         
   char server_addr[16];          

   on                     = 1; 
   flags                  = 0;    
   sprintf(server_addr, "%s", argv[1]);
   server.sin_family      = AF_INET;
   server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_addr);
   server.sin_port        = htons(PORT_NO);
   server_size            = sizeof server;
   client_size            = sizeof client;

   fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 ); 
   if ( fd < 0 ) { 
      error("%s: Socket creation error\n",argv[0]);
      exit(1);
      }

   setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&on, sizeof on);
   setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char *)&on, sizeof on);

   err = connect( fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, server_size);
   if ( err < 0 ) {
      error("%s: Cannot connect to server\n",argv[0]);
      exit(2);
      }

while (1)
   {
    printf(" Message: ");
    scanf("%s",buffer);
    bytes=strlen(buffer)+1;

    trnmsize = send( fd, buffer, bytes, flags );
    if ( trnmsize < 0 ) { 
            error("%s: Cannot send to server\n",argv[0]);
            exit(3);
        }

    printf (" %i bytes have been sent to server.\n", trnmsize-1);

    rcvsize = recv( fd, buffer, bytes, flags );
    if ( rcvsize < 0 ) {
            error("%s: Cannot receive from the socket\n",argv[0]);
            exit(4);
        }

    if (strcmp(buffer,"Transmit is OK."))
            printf (" Acknowledgement has been received from server.\n");
    else
            printf(" Acknowledgement error!");

   }

   close(fd);
   exit(0);
   }
```

Server.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 

#define BUFSIZE 1024                      
#define PORT_NO 2001                      
#define error(a,b) fprintf(stderr, a, b)  

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){

   int fd;                 
   int fdc;                       
   int flags;                      
   struct sockaddr_in server;     
   struct sockaddr_in client;     
   unsigned int server_size;       
   unsigned int client_size;       
   int bytes;                      
   int rcvsize;                    
   int trnmsize;                   
   int err;                        
   char on;                        
   char buffer[BUFSIZE+1];         

   on                     = 1; 
   flags                  = 0; 
   bytes                  = BUFSIZE;
   server.sin_family      = AF_INET;
   server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   server.sin_port        = htons(PORT_NO); 
   server_size            = sizeof server; 
   client_size            = sizeof client; 

   fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 ); 
   if ( fd < 0 ) {
      error("%s: Socket creation error\n",argv[0]);
      exit(1);
      }

   setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&on, sizeof on); 
   setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char *)&on, sizeof on);

   err = bind( fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, server_size);
   if ( err < 0 ) { 
      error("%s: Cannot bind to the socket\n",argv[0]);
      exit(2);
      }

   err = listen( fd, 10);
   if ( err < 0 ) { 
      error("%s: Cannot listen to the socket\n",argv[0]);
      exit(3);
      }

   fdc = accept (fd, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &client_size);
   if ( fdc < 0 ) {
      error("%s: Cannot accept on socket\n",argv[0]);
      exit(4);
      }

while (1)
{

        rcvsize = recv( fdc, buffer, bytes, flags );
        if ( rcvsize < 0 ) { 
            error("%s: Cannot receive from the socket\n",argv[0]);
            exit(5);
        }

        printf (" %i bytes have been received from client.\n Message: %s \n",
           rcvsize-1, buffer);

        sprintf(buffer,"Transmit is OK.");
        bytes = strlen(buffer) + 1;
        trnmsize = send( fdc, buffer, bytes, flags );
        if ( trnmsize < 0 ) { 
            error("%s: Cannot send to server\n",argv[0]);
            exit(6);
        }

        printf (" Acknowledgement has been sent to client.\n");

}

    close (fdc);
    close (fd);
    exit(0);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see this article..https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-cc-handling-multiple-clients-on-server-without-multi-threading/

Comment: thank you @tommybee, managed to solve it using the article!

Comment: It's good to you...happy day...